# Ubuntu 11.10 on Macbook Pro 4,1 - fails during Installation

Tags: 11.10, installation, macbook

I have a Macbook Pro 4,1 It has a 64 bit Intel chipset. I download Ubuntu-11.10-amd-64.iso

I have verified that macbook iso md5sum and the cd boots to the live CD mode too.  The installation completes upto 60% and then fails with the following dialog.

[image: Ubuntu Install Fail]

I am not sure if this a problem with CD has I have tried a couple of times and it has failed with a different CD at a different point in time.

Comment: I think it is CD error. You better go to Ubuntu forum at this link http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=328 for apple users support.

Comment: It is not a CD error. I seem to have tried 3 attempts with different CDs and 1 dvd.

Comment: Then try what Chan-Ho Suh suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing using the mac iso.  There are a couple versions for 11.10 [here](http://cdimages.ubuntu.com/releases/oneiric/release/) depending on what kind of install you want.

Comment: Thanks, I have started the CD Download and I going to try this.

Comment: Unfortunately gave the same error to me. Either it could my CD writing problem or problem with mac hd.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that.  Try the Ubuntu forums and look for the MacBook Pro 4,1 threads.  There tends to be a *lot* more info there on Mac related stuff than here.